# Custom validation not triggering b/c my ruby isn't right

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a painfully noob question, but I have to ask it. I want validation to trip if a particular field, let's call it `:token` isn't a particular string. So, I call my custom validation:

`validate :use_beta_token`

And then I define my validation method

```
def use_beta_token
        errors.add(:token, "Incorrect beta token") if token not 'pizza'
end
```

Whenever I set the token to a string that isn't "pizza", and I test with `valid?` it's coming back `true`. What am I messing up here? I've also tried `if token !== 'pizza'`, but that's not working either. I'm sure the answer is painfully obvious, but I can't seem to dig it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
errors.add(:token, "Incorrect beta token") unless token == 'pizza'
```

the not method works like !, it's a unary boolean operator rather than a binary comparison operator.

as for how to write them, keep it concise. See the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use custom validators for Rails 3 is to define your own Validator class that inherits from ActiveModel::Validator then implement the `validate` method and attach errors like so:

```
# define my validator
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  # implement the method where the validation logic must reside
  def validate(record)
    # do my validations on the record and add errors if necessary
    record.errors[:token] << "Incorrect beta token" unless token == 'pizza'
  end
end
```

Once you define your validator, you must then include it into your model so it can be used and apply it with the `validates_with` method.

```
class ModelName
  # include my validator and validate the record
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```